# How can i compare a string with 3 other strings?

Tags: c#, string, compare

I'm a beginner in c#, and I want to test if a String is not equal to one string OR another string OR another.
I tried the logic operator or ||, but it doesn't seem to work.

The test is always true, even if I enter a correct string
Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated.

**Here's is the code**

```
if (!difficulty.Equals("Beginner") || !difficulty.Equals("Amateur") || !difficulty.Equals("Expert"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `difficulty` for example?

Comment: Why do you negotaize each result? if (NOT EQ or NOT EQ or NOT EQ). Example: You test A for A B C. A is negotaized true = false. B and C therefore true. You would want to remove any ! in your code. Then you have if A = (A, B or C) which is only true because A matches A and not because A does NOT match B and C

Comment: You can then negotaize the entire result, e.g. if (!( A, B, ...)) - or do what dotnetom said. It's basically a logic problem.

Comment: Looks like a candidate for an enum rather than a string, and for string you could `if difficulty != "Beginner" && difficulty != "Amateur" && ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is invalid - the only case it could be valid is if your string is all three values at the same time, which of course is impossible. You need to use and (&&) in this case:

```
if (!difficulty.Equals("Beginner") && !difficulty.Equals("Amateur") && !difficulty.Equals("Expert"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I did not thought about this at all, this is indeed pretty logical. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

String difficulty = "Novice";
            if(!difficulty.Equals("Beginner") && !difficulty.Equals("Amateur") && !difficulty.Equals("Expert")){
                 Console.WriteLine("Do something");
            }

Comment: This is not what he asked for.